# Toggle Navigation Bar causes view to shift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am using the following code to toggle displaying my toolbar and navigation bar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
     //set up gesutre to recognise tap
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("toggle:"))
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

 func toggle(sender: AnyObject) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(navigationController?.toolbarHidden == false, animated: true)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == true
}

override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide
}
```

I currently have an image inside a scrollView. When the navigation bar is animated in, it slides the image down, and when the navigation bar is animated out, it slides the image up. How do i stop this from happening, so that the toolbar appears to slide down on top of the image?

Comment: Can I ask where do you set the scrollView and imageView's frame? Is it done in the Storyboard and you are using AutoLayout fixed to the Top Layout Guide? Or is it in code? In viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: Yes i am setting them in the storyboard. I currently have no constraints for the imageView or the scrollView. Which constraints should be added to solve this issue? @SunburstEnzo

Comment: Hm interesting, this should only happen if you already have a constraint fixed to the Top Layout Guide, as in this case it's always moving, so fixing the top of the scrollView's top to anything but this guide should hopefully fix it. Does the scrollView scroll when the bars disappear?